# Custom 404 Page for a Multilingual (multi language) Website built in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, multilingual

I have a website in two languages, english and dutch.

The english version is in the root (public_html) and the dutch version is in the /nl/ directory.

My website is built in PHP.

When a link is broken (page moved or doesn't exist anymore), then I want dutch speaking people (dutch and belgium people) to be redirected to the 404 page in dutch and the rest to the 404 page in english.

How can I create a custom 404 Error page for this multilingual (multi language) website? Please give me a complete code for example (php and/or .htaccess).

My .htacces file contains the following lines:

```html
# Instructs webbrowsers how to cache content
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 5 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

# Rewrite non-www to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]

# Error Page(s)
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this in `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_en.html

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /nl\x2F.*/">
    ErrorDocument 404 /error_nl.html
</If>
```

The default error page will be the `error_en.html`, and if someone will try to access a page that doesn't exists inside the `/nl/` directory - he will get the content of `error_nl.html` page.

Make sure the **both** error_en.html and error_nl.html files exists in your **root** directory.

> Note the usage of `\x2F` inside the regular expression instead of the `/` char that you cannot escape inside the regular expressions.

Comment: Doesn't work. When i type a wrong url outside the /nl/ directory it shows the error_nl.html version. It always shows the nl version.

Comment: Does your `.htaccess` file contain more lines? Can you put it's content in some pastebin? Which version of Apache do you use? The solution was tested in Apache 2.4.9

Comment: when i run <?php phpinfo() ?> it shows the following info:

Apache 1.3 (apache_hooks) 
Apache 1.3 
Apache 2.0 Filter 
Apache 2.0 Handler  (based on Apache 2.0 Filter code)

Comment: At server API it shows LiteSpeed - LiteSpeed Web Server (LSWS) is a high-performance Apache drop-in replacement.

Comment: As mentioned - the solution I gave works for apache 2.2, since your question was tagged with the `apache` tag. It seems like you are not running an Apache server, so this solution might not work well for you. According to lsws config - they have full support for the apache-config style, however since the server is not the same I'm not sure it really works there.

Comment: This is effective solution for multi-language error 404 documents. Thank you.

Comment: @TadasV. glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect error.html to show a page generated by a PHP file which you can generate multilingual output.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^error\.html$ error.php [NC,R]
```

but the `error.html` file shouldn't exist in your server, instead it'll be shown to the user.